# What URI to put to Response.created when putting a new row to mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, post

I am making a Restful service where at some point using POST i add a new row to the table. So by looking [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) **201** for success seemed like a good idea. Though what made me confused is what should i put in the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) if i use Response.created(URI)?

Answer (score 0):

URI should contain path to newly created resource

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html

public static Response.ResponseBuilder created(java.net.URI location)
location - the URI of the new resource

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2
"The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response"

Comment: So if i have the table mentioned above in mysql, i just put in `public static URI create(String str)` where str the URL of the page containing the mysql table?

Comment: something like uri="base/table/rowId". so you can call delete uri and delete that row.

Comment: one second.. If i open in phpmyadmin the URL looks like this when i am in the desired table in which i want to insert the new row: `http://localhost:12354/phpmyadmin/#PMAURL-9:sql.php?db=mobilecompanysite&table=mobilecompanies&server=1&target=&token=8c1f4ff64a2ef48037960cac9a811244`  Though it does not look anything like `base/table/rowId`...

Comment: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/restful-web-services-example-in-java-with-jersey-spring-and-mybatis/

you can get more info by "java rest database table example" query